# Process task structure between Docker and Host

Tags: process, docker

How the process task structure is different in both docker and the host process any specific module is differed in docker apart from host?

Answer (score 2):

Since processed are represented in kernel by structure called ‘`task_struct`', that structure is the same in a container.

A container is based on **[system calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)** to the host kernel, and any kernel-related structure comes directly from said kernel.

See "[Architecting Containers: Why Understanding User Space vs. Kernel Space Matters](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/07/29/architecting-containers-part-1-user-space-vs-kernel-space/)"

> A typical program gets access to resources in the kernel through layers of abstraction similar to the following diagram:

[image: https://rhelblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/user-space-vs-kernel-space-system-calls-gears.png?w=300]

> The kernel provides abstraction for security, hardware, and internal data structures. The open() system call is commonly used to get a file handle
>
> Notice in the following drawing that `bash` makes a `getpid()` call which requests its own process identity.
> Also, notice that the `cat` command requests access to `/etc/hosts` with a file `open()` call.

[image: https://rhelblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/user-space-vs-kernel-space-basic-system-calls.png?w=584&h=219]

Comment: Is there any link that provides in detail of this system calls from containers are passed to host kernel?

Comment: @SowndaryaK Yes, I have edited the answer with such a link.

Comment: @SowndaryaK see also http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/09/17/architecting-containers-part-2-why-the-user-space-matters-2/