# Can docker use host filesystem instead of an image?

Tags: docker

Reading [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/659557/os-docker-container-what-is-the-difference-with-a-vm-then), I understood that containers use a base image (like ubuntu) for root filesystem. Now my question is if is necessary to download a base image, if I have exactly the same OS (like ubuntu 14.04).

Is that base image redundant?

Answer (score 2):

First, if your service run in that container is statically linked (like a [Go application](https://golang.org/)), you could [COPY that app in a "scratch" container](https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/) (which is an [*empty* one](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/)! No OS at all)

Second, an app in a container can only make [system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117091/6309) to the host kernel,  it doesn't see the host filesystem (beside what is mounted by volumes)

The base image is there to guarantee that the runtime will be **reproducible**: any user call (dynamic linking) will be done against the exact same OS (base image), even if you have updated/upgraded your base OS.

Finally, a base image "ubuntu" is not the same as an actual Ubuntu OS: it is a compact subset (a root filesystem, without the graphical X-11 part), and it used by docker, with UnionFS, as one of the layers of disk blocks inside a container.