# If docker uses virtual machine to run on a mac then what is its advantage over vagrant?

Tags: docker, vagrant, boot2docker, docker-machine

So I have read this in many places that docker is faster and more efficient because it uses containers over VMs but when I downloaded docker on my mac I realized that it uses virtual box to run the containers. I believe on a linux machine docker doesn't need virtual box and can run on Linux Kernel. Is this correct ?

Back to original question. Is docker still faster/efficient because it uses a single VM to run multiple containers as opposed to Vargrant's new VM for every environment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe on a linux machine docker doesn't need virtual box and can run on Linux Kernel. Is this correct ?

Yes, hence the need for a VirtualBox Linux VM (using a [TinyCore](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/) distribution)

> Is docker still faster/efficient because it uses a single VM to run multiple containers as opposed to Vargrant's new VM for every environment ?

Yes, because of the lack of [Hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) simulating the hardware and OS: here you can launch *multiple* containers all using directly the kernel (through [direct system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117091/6309)), without having to simulate an OS.
(Note: May 2018, [**gVisor**](https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/05/gvisor-container-sandbox) is another option: a container, simulating an OS!)

[image: vm vs container]

See more at "[How is Docker different from a normal virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16047306/6309)".

Of course, remember that [Vagrant can use a docker provider](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/basics.html).
That means you don't have to always provision a full-fledged VM with Vagrant, but rather images and containers.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.image = "foo/bar"
  end
end
```

See [Vagrant docker provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer.